# Facebook C# SDK - .NET 3.5 & Dynamic objects

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have downloaded the Graph C# SDK for facebook, the examples are very helpful and easy to understand however i come unstuck when trying to use the dynamic object type as the return object for a FacebookApp.Get("me") call.

I'v never used dynamics before so i did a bit of reasearch and it seems they are new to Visual Studio 2010, which is the version i am using but i cant use the latest framework because of my production environment...

Is there a type i can use instead or is there a different way to go about this using the 3.5 framework? here is an example from the source files provided with the binary for the framework.

```
dynamic myInfo = app.Get("me");
lblTitle.Text = myInfo.name;
```

I get an error stating that i may be missing an assembely reference for type dynamic.

Any and all help is greatly apreciated! looking forward to getting to grips with this SDK!!

Comment: I'm glad you asked the question because I'm looking for a way to use the sdk from .net 3.5 also (they include a 3.5 folder so I think it should work).  Here's my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675364/  Keep an eye on it. Between the two of us maybe somebody will answer one of our questions.

Answer (score 5):

If you want strongly typed objects there is a very easy way to do that. See here: https://gist.github.com/906471

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");

var result = fb.Get<FBUser>("/me");

string name = result.Name;

MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);

[DataContract]
public class FBUser {
   [DataMember(Name="name")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   [DataMember(Name="first_name")]
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at this article http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-Writing-your-first-Facebook-Application.aspx

```
var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");

var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)fb.Get("/me");
var name = (string)result["name"];

MessageBox.Show("Hi " + name);
```

You will need to cast it to **IDictionary<string, object>**

Answer (score 1):

Building on some of the other answers here, the dynamic objects are really JSON objects that are returned from the facebook api.  The SDK uses dynamic type to create a nicer interface to the underlying data.

I didn't like the idea of casting the objects to IDictionary each time so I took it a step further and created a facade object that provides a strongly-typed access method to the data.

```
public class FBPerson : FBBase
{
    #region constructor
    public FBPerson(object personObject)
        : base(personObject)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public string first_name
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("first_name"); }
    }
    public string last_name
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("last_name"); }
    }
    public string name
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("name"); }
    }
    public string email
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("email"); }
    }
    public string id
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("id"); }
    }
    public string link
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("link"); }
    }
    public string username
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("username"); }
    }
    public string location
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("location"); }
    }
    public string gender
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("gender"); }
    }
    public string timezone
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("timezone"); }
    }
    public string locale
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("locale"); }
    }
    public string verified
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("verified"); }
    }
    public string updated_time
    {
        get { return ExtractValueAsString("updated_time"); }
    }
    #endregion

}
```

And the base class (so you can create facades for other SDK objects)...

```
public class FBBase
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> fbCollection = null;
    public FBBase(object collection)
    {
        fbCollection = (IDictionary<string, object>)collection;
    }

    protected string ExtractValueAsString(string value)
    {
        Validate();
        return fbCollection[value].ToString();
    }
    protected void Validate()
    {
        if (fbCollection == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("null collection object");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a much easier way to do this. See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674669/facebook-c-sdk-net-3-5-dynamic-objects/5572620#5572620

Answer (score -1):

dynamic is C# 4.0 .Net 4.0 not .Net 3.5

Comment: I thought so, im not sure of how i can acheieve the same result within the limits of the 3.5 framework? can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You will need reflection ; have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2135533/c-3-5-dlr-expression-dynamic-question

Comment: No ideas anyone? surly sombody must be using this with .net 3.5? Thanks!

Comment: I was afraid that reflection might be the answer. Maybe I'll just have get 4.0 installed on our production environment instead.

Comment: Reflection goes over my head.... I dont understand why the SDK cant just drop the collection to a known type? or a key/value pair? I really cant upgrade to 4.0!!

Comment: To clarify you DO NOT need reflection. Use IDictionary<string, object> in place of dynamic in .Net 3.5.