# Accessing Facebook C# SDK result Object using .NET 3.5 API?

Tags: dynamic, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk, weakly-typed

Consider the following in .NET 3.5 (using the Bin\Net35\Facebook*.dll assemblies):

```
using Facebook;

var app = new FacebookApp();
var result = app.Get("me");
// want to access result properties with no dynamic
```

... in the absence of the C# 4.0 `dynamic` keyword this provides only generic `object` members.
 **How best should I access the facebook properties of this result object?**

Are there helper or utility methods or stronger types in the facebook C# SDK, or should I use standard .NET reflection techniques?

Comment: Similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674669/facebook-c-sdk-net-3-5-dynamic-objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [code sample](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code%20Examples&referringTitle=Documentation) shows 3.5 usage, without needing the C# `dynamic` keyword:

```
// Using IDictionary<string, object> (.Net 3.5)
var client = new FacebookClient();
var me = (IDictionary<string,object>)client.Get("me");
string firstName = (string)me["first_name"];
string lastName = (string)me["last_name"];
string email = (string)me["email"];
```

Comment: For anyone else who just copied that and wondered why it doesn't compile, the correct spelling is 'IDictionary' :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
var accesstoken = Session["AccessToken"].ToString();
var client = new FacebookClient(accesstoken);
dynamic result = client.Get("me", new { fields = "name,id,email" });
Details details = new Details();
details.Id = result.id;
details.Name = result.name;
details.Email = result.email;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also create a facade object around the IDictionary, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674669/facebook-c-sdk-net-3-5-dynamic-objects/5516576#5516576).