# Is there a Facebook SDK for .NET that works with 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, facebook-c#-sdk

When I first created my site, there were no .NET SDKs for Facebook so I wrote my own.  It was pretty hacky, but it worked.  Due to various Facebook changes, it's now broken beyond repair so I figured I'd use a *real* library.  The one I found was the [Facebook C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk).

However, it seems you can only download the source and compile it, and it seems it requires .NET 4.0 to compile.  Also, looking through the code it seems to use .NET features such as `System.Threading.Tasks`.  I'm still on .NET 3.5 and cannot upgrade at the moment.  I'm wondering if there's a) a way to make this project work on 3.5, or b) another library that would be better in my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook C# SDK - .NET 3.5 & Dynamic objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674669/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-net-3-5-dynamic-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook C# SDK supports .net 3.5sp1.

You can download using nuget.

If you are using VS 2008 where nuget package manager is not support, you can download using nuget command line tool. (http://nuget.codeplex.com/releases)

```
nuget install Facebook
```

For pre-release version you can download using the following command.

```
nuget install Facebook -pre
```

Comment: Thanks!  Yea, I'm still on VS2008, so I'll try that out.  I wish the binaries for various frameworks were just posted on Github though.

Comment: we will post binaries for v6 once we hit rtw, but since it is at alpha stage we are looking for early adapters. maintaining multiple downloads is also a maintenance problem for us.

Comment: Oh don't worry about it, the `nuget` method worked great.  In fact, once I had `facebook.dll` it took me around 20 min to update my code and get everything all working again.  Fantastic library, guys!

Answer (score 1):

I have websites in .Net 3.5 using the latest code from the Facebook C# SDK.  However, here's what I do.  I use the "client" Facebook.dll to do all the stuff. Yeah, I don't get some of the wizbang session information, etc.  But I do get full access to the API.  I use javascript for authentication then AJAX the access token to the server.

Comment: Yeah, all I need is to support logon.  I need to get the session cookie and see if it's valid, no *wizbang* stuff.  The question is where do you get `Facebook.dll`?  All I could find was source..

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how committed to making the new SDK work with your codebase.

You could branch the code from [Facebook C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk) as you listed and replace all the task stuff with System.Threading.Threads, but that could result in a lot of work if there is extensive use of Tasks.

Or you could update your SDK to just address the areas you currently require until you can move to .NET 4. At least that way your project won't need reworking, just your internal library that your project is already referencing.